# How to set the header colour of bootstrap vue date form picker?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrapvue's form date picker. How do I achieve the following?

1. Change the header colour, ie where the Month is
2. Change the day colour while hovered over? Currently it's grey by default
3. Currently you can change the selected date's colour via the property `selected-variant` but it only accepts:

```
'secondary', 'success', 'danger', 'warning', 'info'
```

Is there a way I can pass in a hex value?

I've been looking at the docs, but wasn't able to find information for above:
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

> 1. Change the header colour, ie where the Month is

```
.b-calendar .b-calendar-grid-caption {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

> 2. Change the day colour while hovered over? Currently it's grey by default

```
span.btn.border-0.rounded-circle.text-nowrap.btn-outline-light.text-dark.font-weight-bold:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

> 3. Currently you can change the selected date's colour via the property selected-variant but it only accepts: 'secondary', 'success', 'danger', 'warning', 'info'

```
[aria-selected="true"] > span {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: I would give you two up votes if I could. Can you tell me how you found those out? There's also other colours I want to modify, can you explain how you determined the styling necessary?

Comment: You're welcome. :) 1. Visit https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker. 2. Press the F12 key (i.e., use `Developer tools`). 3. Under `Elements` you can find HTML and CSS of the page you are visiting. Find elements you want to target. ;)

Comment: Never thought about doing that, learnt something, thank you

Comment: Glad to help you. Happy coding!